# Joda Time bad formatting when using locales other than english

Tags: android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I'm using Joda Time 2.9.9 in Android. When the Locale is set to english, calls like `datetime.monthOfYear().getAsText(locale)` and `datetime.monthOfYear().getAsShortText(locale)` return strings formatted like `February` and `Feb` respectively.

But when the locale is to to spanish (es) it returns strings such as `february` and `feb.` (actual values are in spanish, I translated them).

Is there any way to make it return nice formatted strings, capitalized and without dots, when using other locales?

And a bonus question: If there is no way, is subclassing the datetime class and formatting the string there a good idea?

Comment: Other libs like ICU4j or my lib Time4A (having its own i18n-text-resources) would be so much better for internationalization.

Comment: @MenoHochschild sadly I'm way too invested in JodaTime to switch. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Joda-Time gets this info from the JVM's `DateFormatSymbols` and I'm not sure if those can be replaced via API (probably you can do it using reflection, but I personally don't like to do these things in production code).

Anyway, I think you can adapt the solution found in this question: [Month name in genitive (Polish locale) with Joda-Time DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188316/month-name-in-genitive-polish-locale-with-joda-time-datetimeformatter)

PS: I can't reproduce the error, the code below:

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime();
System.out.println(datetime.monthOfYear().getAsText(new Locale("es")));
System.out.println(datetime.monthOfYear().getAsShortText(new Locale("es")));
```

gives me "febrero" and "feb"